# Lost internet connection after using 2 netsh commands (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, internet, connection, netsh

I have tried to redirect a certain IP of outgoing packets in my PC to localhost. I started CMD, and entered this:

`netsh int ip add addr 3 146.112.61.106/32 st=ac sk=tr`

About 2 minutes afterwards, I entered this:

`netsh int ip delete addr 3 146.112.61.106`

Both commands returned no output (empty line).

After the second command, my ethernet icon in the lower right side of the toolbar showed a yellow triangle, and Google Chrome says "There is no Internet connection".

I have resetted my router and restarted the PC, but it didn't help - I still don't have an Internet connection right now.

The WiFi from the router, though, works perfectly fine - it's just my PC, which is directly connected to the router in Ethernet, that doesn't have an Internet connection.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

From an elevated Command Prompt reset your network stack by running the command:

```
netsh int ip reset
```

You will have to restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

According to this Microsoft [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility):

> This has the same effect as removing and reinstalling TCP/IP.

**Note:** If you have configured any network adapters with static IP information you will have to re-enter those settings.